# Precise meaning of weak convergence of empirical measure (related to Interacting Particle Systems)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Given a "almost independent" finite sequence of $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ having a common probability distribution $\mu$ (where ''almost independent'' could mean for example $|\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)| \leq \varepsilon_N$, with $\varepsilon_N \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$), and consider the so-called empirical measure $$\rho_N := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N \delta_{X_k}.$$ I am expecting to have results of the type $\rho_N \rightharpoonup \rho$ (weak convergence of probability measures) for some $\rho \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ represents the space of probability measures on $\mathbb R$. What confuses me is that by definition of the weak convergence, I need to show $$''\int f \mathrm{d}\rho_N \to \int f \mathrm{d}\rho''$$ for all $f \in C_{\mathrm{b}}\left(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\right)$. But what does the preceding sentence mean exactly? If I view $\rho_N$ as a "random vaeriable'' belonging to the space $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\int f \mathrm{d}\rho_N$ is clearly random and not deterministic. Also, how does function in $C_{\mathrm{b}}\left(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\right)$ look like? By Riesz representation, I know the dual of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in $C_{\mathrm{b}}\left(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\right)$, but I guess the space $C_{\mathrm{b}}\left(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\right)$ is strictly larger than  the dual of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$? I am sorry my understanding is a bit vague. Thank you guys very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific about what kind of convergence you are looking for? Or is your question exactly about how to define convergence in this situation?

In empirical process theory, there are a few notions of convergence. [Glivenko-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) gives a type of *uniform convergence* of the form $$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - F(x)| \overset{\text{almost surely}}{\to} 0$$
where $F_n$ is the CDF of the empirical measure. [Donsker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) gives a type of "convergence in distribution" of random walks to Brownian motion in Skorohod space.

Comment: Hi, I mean "weak convergence of probabilities measures", meaning you have convergence against bounded continuous test functions. If $\rho_N$ is deterministic then $\rho_N \rightharpoonup \rho$ iff $\int fd\rho_N \to \int fd\rho$ for every $f \in C_{\mathrm{b}}\left(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{R} \right)$

Comment: @FeiCao Yes, but as you already noted in your question, this definition is problematic when the measures themselves are random. This is why I am wondering if you are coming up with this question yourself, or if there is some context where this notion is already defined for a sequence of random measures.

Comment: You are right, in the case of a sequence of random elements $\rho_N$ from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, I am not sure how to define the notion of "weak convergence"...